# New kateproject in kate

Tags: ide, project, kate

How can I add a new kateproject to the Kate editor ?

I have created a bookssimple.kateproject file as described here: 
http://kate-editor.org/2012/11/02/using-the-projects-plugin-in-kate/

```
{"name": "books_simple", "files": [ { "directory": "perl",  "recursive": 1 } ]}
```

But how can I tell Kate to use this file ?

Answer (score 2):

The project file must be named `.kateproject` and NOT `bookssimple.kateproject`. Then it will work. Just open a file in the respective folder or subfolder, and the projects plugin will automatically find the file `.kateproject`.

Answer (score 1):

You simply open a file from the directory in question, and kate will automatically load the rest of the project